# QTP: Unable to use CSS & Index properties while trying to identify object

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp

I'm trying to run the line of code below in my script, but I get an error saying that more than one object with these properties was found on the page.

```
Browser("browser").Page("page").WebElement("css:=.normalDayOfMonth").Click
```

So, I tried adding an index, as shown below:

```
Browser("browser").Page("page").WebElement("css:=.normalDayOfMonth", "index:=0").Click
```

But now it's not detecting any object at all. Could anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

---

**Edit:** For anyone else who comes across this, it turned out I was using QTP10 and as Motti pointed out below, CSS and Xpath support was only added in QTP11.

Comment: The following works for me on IE8  `Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebElement("css:=.gbts", "index:=0").Highlight`. Please see if it works for you, if not try to post some more information.

Comment: I'm getting a general run error for that? I was using the regular Google.com URL

Comment: I have QTP11 with patch QTPWEB_00090 installed, perhaps you should try installing this patch (if you don't already have it).

Comment: I have QTP10, and I don't think it has the highlight function? I tried using the click function, but it reproduced the same problem. I'm on a corporate computer, so unfortunately I can't add any patches. :( Is there anything obvious I could be overlooking?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a workaround for QTP10, please take a look.

Comment: The workaround worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for using `CSS` and `XPath` to identify test objects was added in QTP11, in your comments you say that you're using QTP10 which would explain why you're facing problems...

What's probably happening is that QTP is ignoring `css` as an unrecognizd property so your description matches all elements and then when you add `index:=0` it brings one of the invisible elements (e.g `HEAD` or `HTML`) which can't be clicked.

If all you're trying to do is match the `className` you can use QTP's `class` identification property `("class:=normalDayOfMonth")`.

BTW the `Highlight` function is an undocumented function similar to the object repository's highlight functionality and can be very useful in troubleshooting tests.

Comment: I've also successfully been able to use CSS in other cases though. If it wasn't in QTP 10, how is that possible?

Comment: @khalid13 are you sure? This is very strange, AFAIK they were added in QTP11.

Comment: Yessir, this line of code I'm using elsewhere in the project works like a charm: `.Link("css:=.selectable","index:=2").Click` That's why I was confused as to why it wasn't working for WebElements. @Motti

Comment: @khalid13 the [web](http://www.quicklearnqtp.com/2010/12/qtp-10-vs-qtp-11.html) backs me [up](http://www.learnqtp.com/new-features-qtp-11-aka-functional-testing-11/) (as well as QTP's documentation) that CSS was added in QTP11. It could be that when you use `Link` QTP only returns `<a>` elements and the `.selectable` is ignored, can you create a demo page with both selectable and un-selectable elements and see if the CSS is doing anything?

Comment: I just created a webpage to test out my theory, and it appears that you are right - it was ignoring the CSS class specification and simply picking up the first link available. I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer; thanks for all your help. :) @Motti